# How to disable javascript modal popup ads

Tags: firefox, internet, popups

For many years I have blocked popup ads with AdBlock Plus.

But it seems more and more these past couple months there is a "new" kind of popup overtaking the web.  They are javascript based "modal" popups which ABP is powerless over.  See attached for an example.

Is there a way to kill these ads without breaking the functionality of anything I need?

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure you will have to disable javascript to stop those kinds of Ajax modal-style pop-ups.

Comment: block out jquery ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is although it appears as if it is a pop up, it is actually just HTML giving the impression it's a pop up. It is often called an overlay. Meaning on some sites, it will be junk (as per the screen shot), but other sites very much required (like a shopping basket preview screen).

Whilst it may block adverts it is possible it could block useful things, such as a discount pop up or cookie policy notifications, which until agreed won't let you proceed.

For FireFox and Chrome, there is a plugin called [BehindTheOverlay](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/behind_the_overlay/) which may give you what you want (similar to AdBlocker but for overlay). Chrome also has an extra plugin called `overlay blocker`. It is not perfect for many reasons and as already mentioned, do it at your own risk (as it may stop some sites working as intended).

Lastly, AdBlock plus may be able to help as it can be customised, see this forum for more detail https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18595

You also have the option of disabling JavaScript. I know this is unlikely to suffice, but it's still an option.

Comment: It seems like there could be a universal blacklist/filter though that is shared by all users of some client-side mod addon like Stylish or GreaseMonkey. If every user's block choices were aggregated in the filter DB (and given some popularity threshold before being committed), all users would benefit. I'm really surprised something like this hasn't been implemented yet. Even ABP with the old school popup required filter subscriptions to work optimally. Is this really that different?

Answer (score 3):

You might take a look at the [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) plugin.  It is a bit more convenient than global disable of javascript.

Comment: You can also ScriptNo if your using Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, seems like the only valid option I've found.  Not sure I have the patience though to add tons of legit sites to the whitelist.  The great thing about ABP were the filter subscriptions.

Comment: Only very slightly more convenient.  YesScript is better if you want to block certain sites

Comment: My  recommendation is 8 years old. Guessing YesScript didn't exist  back then.  Snarky comment not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Overlay Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/overlay-blocker/inncfpkneoefpgnoggjhcnkjhbcdeimo) chrome extension. It stops these popups automatically now and no longer breaks pages.

Comment: You get 8 free blocks a month, than you can pay $19 to upgrade. The animation is choppy, but it works on the two sites i've tested it out on. - here is the website, check it out $40 off -- http://www.overlayblock.com/ - weak how there is no lifetime off. 20 years @$19 is insane for this service.. what a jip.