# How to block all in-page pop-ups?

Tags: firefox, popups, adblock, advertisements

My questions is about those pop-ups that cover the entire page and are just regular DOM elements such as `<div>` but I don't know what they are called. They usually contain some social media links or ask you to register on the website or subscribe to their newsletter.

Is there a way to reliably detect those elements and block them from taking over the screen or hide them? A Firefox add-on or Greasemonkey script?

Here's an example of what i'm referring to:

[image]

Comment: How would a software (assuming it would be a generic tool) differentiate a valid modal and an ad modal? For none-generic solutions there are several lists for your ad-blocker of choice. Blocking scripts altogether would probably work as well, depending on the underlying markup.

Comment: In a sense you're asking about Software Recommendation which would be off-topic in addition there isn't really a good answer to this aside from "None" or "No". You seem to know about DOM so ask yourself what would identify a "bad" DOM Element that does a modal from one which is "good". Short of using filter lists there is probably no much you can do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/433613/105108.

Answer (score 0):

you can block some of those popups as well as other social content using [adblock plus](https://adblockplus.org/). after installing, you need to add a filter list called *Fanboy Annoyances List* which can be downloaded from: [Fanboy website](https://www.fanboy.co.nz/).

Answer (score -1):

Another option is a browser called Slimjet. It uses Chrome but is quite efficient in blocking ads...not as efficient as adblock plus, but still quite useful.