# Are there any maintained blocklists for modal website popups?

Tags: popups, web-filtering, ublock-origin

I use uBlock Origin to block ads. I also use it to block non-advertisement annoyances, such as registration popups and overlays. I select the offending element(s) with the UBO element picker, create a filter, and it goes away forever.

But it's a manual, tedious process, and must be repeated on lots of sites. I don't want to do it by hand any more. I could turn off javascript or apply Noscript, but that would break many sites completely. Also, I hear that [many offenders are not actually script-based](https://superuser.com/a/893255/633402), but creative abuse of stock HTML/CSS. Noscript won't help with that.

uBlock Origin uses filter lists for blocking ads. A filter list for whatever-it-is-the-element-picker-does *ought* to work fine. Does there exist a maintained list for blocking such elements?

(I use UBO on Firefox, but lists for other applications are fine provided they can be mechanically converted. The important parts are "list of offending page elements to nuke" and "kept updated as websites find new ways to interrupt their own content".)